# AngularJS in Round-trip applications

Tags: angularjs, web-applications

I have started developing in AngularJS to implement a single-page application. The domain (Single-Page application) looks really interesting; can we develop a round-trip application in which we will have many pages, using AngularJS in some parts of the application. For example, if we are developing a Employees invoice which consists of Employee Management, Invoice management etc.; Can all employee management tasks be implemented in a single page and the Invoice Management in the other page?

Best Regards,
Mouli.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can devleop multple page applications.

Here is  a good post

[Is AngularJS just for single-page applications (SPAs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231251/is-angular-js-just-for-single-page-applications-spa)

[AngularJS Multi-Page App Site Boilerplate Site Structure Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556650/angularjs-multi-page-app-site-boilerplate-site-structure-advice)